# How do I run the same JUnit test multiple times with different test data each time?

Tags: java, unit-testing, junit

I am just getting started with unit testing. I did the junit tutorial from a pdf from the tutorial points website. So my question is, I want to test my shunting yard algorithm and my RPNEvaluator.

The constructors (and any other variables to help you out with the context) look like this:

ShuntingYard.java:

```
private ArrayList<String> tokens = new ArrayList<String>();
public ShuntingYard(ArrayList<String> tokens) {
    this.tokens = tokens;
}
```

RPNEvaluator.java:

```
private Queue<String> polishExpression;
public RPNEvaluator(Queue<String> exp) {
    polishExpression = exp;
}
```

ShuntingYard.java has a method called toRpn() which will take an ArrayList and return a Queue after some processing.

RPNEvaluator has a method called evaluate which will take a Queue type and return a double after some processing.

With Junit I am trying to write some unit tests and I wanted to know if this start was the best way to go about it:

```
package testSuite;

import static org.junit.Assert.fail;

import java.util.ArrayList;

import org.junit.Before;
import org.junit.Test;

public class ExpressionEvaluationTest {

    /**
     * Initialise the lists to be used
     */
    @Before
    public void beforeTest() {
        ArrayList<String> exprOne = new ArrayList<String>();
        exprOne.add("3");
        exprOne.add("+");
        exprOne.add("4");
        exprOne.add("*");
        exprOne.add("2");
        exprOne.add("/");
        exprOne.add("(");
        exprOne.add("1");
        exprOne.add("-");
        exprOne.add("5");
        exprOne.add(")");
        exprOne.add("^");
        exprOne.add("2");
        exprOne.add("^");
        exprOne.add("3");

        ArrayList<String> exprTwo = new ArrayList<String>();
        exprTwo.add("80");
        exprTwo.add("+");
        exprTwo.add("2");

        ArrayList<String> exprThree = new ArrayList<String>();
        exprThree.add("2");
        exprThree.add("/");
        exprThree.add("1");
        exprThree.add("*");
        exprThree.add("4");

        ArrayList<String> exprFour = new ArrayList<String>();
        exprFour.add("11");
        exprFour.add("-");
        exprFour.add("(");
        exprFour.add("2");
        exprFour.add("*");
        exprFour.add("4");
        exprFour.add(")");

        ArrayList<String> exprFive = new ArrayList<String>();
        exprFive.add("120");
        exprFive.add("/");
        exprFive.add("(");
        exprFive.add("10");
        exprFive.add("*");
        exprFive.add("4");
        exprFive.add(")");

        ArrayList<String> exprSix = new ArrayList<String>();
        exprSix.add("600");
        exprSix.add("*");
        exprSix.add("2");
        exprSix.add("+");
        exprSix.add("20");
        exprSix.add("/");
        exprSix.add("4");
        exprSix.add("*");
        exprSix.add("(");
        exprSix.add("5");
        exprSix.add("-");
        exprSix.add("3");
        exprSix.add(")");

    }

    @Test
    public void test() {

    }

}
```

I was going to put this in the before() method:
    ShuntingYard sy = new ShuntingYard(/*arraylist here*/);

And then in the test, pass the lists to the algorithm. My question is that I think I am going the long way around it, would it be better to have a parameterised annotation and pass those lists as a list of parameters?

and a further question: if a test for any of the ArrayLists passes then I am sure I can execute a subsequent test to the RPNEvaluator evaluate method. I hope I haven't been ambiguous.

Help would be very much appreciated.

Comment: note: you can shorten list initialization ArrayList<String> exprThree = new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList("2","/","1","*","4"));

Comment: Thank you, I writing them out long so I could practice so yanking and pasting and navigating with vim, to get used to the controls with repetition.

Comment: I think your question is, "What's the best way to run a JUnit test multiple times with different test data each time?". Is that correct?

Comment: @MikeB Yes that is essentially my question.

Comment: @BoristheSpider yes that is the way I was thinking to go.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would come at it a little differently. Instead of just creating several sets of test data and calling the same test each time break it up in to something meaningful. Instead of writing one test called `test()` write several separate tests for each aspect of `ShuntingYard`. For example:

```
@Test public void 
itDoesntDivideByZero()
{
    ArrayList<String> divideByZeroExpression = Arrays.asList("5", "0", "/");
    // Add code to call your method with this data here
    // Add code to verify your results here
}

@Test public void 
itCanAdd()
{
    ArrayList<String> simpleAdditionExpression = Arrays.asList("1", "2", "+");
    // Add code to call your method with this data here
    // Add code to verify your results here
}
```

and so on. This will make your JUnit output much easier to read. When there's a failure you know that it failed while trying to add, or it failed while trying to evaluate an expression that would cause a divide by zero, etc. Doing it the way you have it in the original you'd only know that it failed in the `test()` method.

Each of the tests here does 3 things:

1. Arranges the test data
2. Performs some action with that data
3. Asserts that the results of the action are as expected

This `Arrange, Assert, Act` idiom is very common in automated testing. You may also see it called `Given, When, Then` as in, "Given these conditions, when I call this method, then I should get this result".

Try to get out of the mindset of writing one test to test an entire class or method. Write a test to test one part of a method. Consider this class:

```
public class Adder {
    public int addOneTo(int someNumber) {
        return someNumber + 1;
    }
}
```

You might end up with a test suite that looks like:

```
@Test public void
itAddsOne()
{
    int numberToAddTo = 1;
    int result = new Adder().addOneTo(numberToAddTo);
    assertEquals("One plus one is two", 2, result);
}

@Test(expected="NullPointerException.class") public void
itChokesOnNulls()
{
   new Adder().addOneTo((Integer)null);
}

@Test public void
itDoesntOverflow()
{
    int result = new Adder().addOneTo(Integer.MAX_VALUE);
    // do whatever here to make sure it worked correctly
}
```

And so on.

Comment: yes this is a good way to look at it, I will be testing some methods several times, but this approach is really nice. Thank you.

Comment: Testing the same method several times in different tests is perfectly fine. I edited my answer to add some more info.

Answer (score 1):

The advise from Mike B is very good, try to separate your test thinking in one test per behavior/functionality.

For make your test more readable i probably write a static constructor for the class ShuntingYard that receives a string, then you can write:

ShuntingYard addition = ShuntingYard.createFromExpresion("2+2");
  assertThat(addition.getRpn().evaluate(), is(4));

you can refactor a little more and ends with something like that:

assertThat(evaluate("2+2"), is(4))

That is easy to understand an and easy to read, and in addition write more test with diferent scenarios its one-line of code.

Other option its to write parametrized test, one example: http://www.mkyong.com/unittest/junit-4-tutorial-6-parameterized-test/, but in my opinion are really ugly. This test are normally called "data driven test" and are used when you want to test the same code with different input values.

For this data-driven test a much better option its to use something like spock, a groovy framework for testing that allows you to write incredible semantic test, and of course you can use for testing java code, check this out: http://docs.spockframework.org/en/latest/data_driven_testing.html